# Mocking class by replacing it

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, pytest

imagine you have a module

```
from module.my_module import Foo


def my_function():
    foo = Foo()
    return whatewer_can_happen(foo)
```

that you want to test like this

```
class TestFoo:
    def __init__():
         pass
    
    def dont_care():
        return 9


def test_something():
    with mock.patch('tested_module.Foo') as mocked_class:
        mocked_class.side_effect = lambda *args: TestFoo(*args)
        assert tested_module.my_function() == 'not important'
```

essentially as if you wanted to inject the TestFoo in place of Foo
(example wont work ofc, only for illustration)

How to mock the `Foo` class in the tested module without changing the tested code? If it is not possible, why - how are classes in python so different to functions that mocking them is not possible?

I am not looking for ways to do it differently(factory function/mocking only class functions directly etc)

It would in some cases just be helpful (and more readable) to be able to write mock classes and inject them for use into the tested module

Comment: You can just pass your mock class as a replacement: `with mock.patch('tested_module.Foo', TestFoo):`. Check the documentation of `mock.patch`, specifically the `new` and `new_callable` parameters. If you don't pass a replacement object, a `MagicMock` is created, but that is only the default.

Comment: @MrBean Bremen oh right, read the doc .. I had trouble finding it on SO and google though, would you mind posting an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always provide your own mock instead of the default `MagicMock` instance by passing it to the `mock.patch` call:

```py
def test_something():
    with mock.patch('tested_module.Foo', TestFoo):
        assert tested_module.my_function() == 'not important'
```

Note that you can't use `side_effect` here, because your new object is not a `Mock` object. Also, if you use the decorator version, there will be no extra argument for the mock:

```py
@mock.patch('tested_module.Foo', TestFoo):
def test_something():
    assert tested_module.my_function() == 'not important'
```

Here is the relevant part of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=propertymock#unittest.mock.patch):

> If *new* is omitted, then the target is replaced with an `AsyncMock` if the patched object is an async function or a `MagicMock` otherwise. If `patch()` is used as a decorator and *new* is omitted, the created mock is passed in as an extra argument to the decorated function. If `patch()` is used as a context manager the created mock is returned by the context manager.